# Force Artifactory to use numerical comparison when searching?

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I am trying to find the latest (or earliest, depending on comparison operator) version of an RPM package (**the RPM bit is important**). I am using AQL query similar to this one:

```
items.find( 
   { "$and" : [ 
     { "@rpm.metadata.name": { "$eq": "awesome_package"}}, 
     { "@rpm.metadata.version": { "$gte": "19.300.0.58"}} ] 
   })
   .include("@rpm.metadata.version")
   .sort( { "$asc": [ "name" ]})
```

As already answered by Artifactory KnowledgeBase, [it's impossible to sort on properties](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-do-i-use-artifactory-query-language-to-sort-on-properties/), so instead of just sorting on `@rpm.metadata.version` and taking the first top result by using `.limit(1)` I must use property condition in the `find` clause.

It appears though that Artifactory's built-in comparison is purely lexicographic, so for the query above I get the following result:

```
{
"results" : [ {
  "repo" : "yum-private-local",
  "path" : "some/path",
  "name" : "awesome_package-19.300.0.9-1.noarch.rpm",
  "properties" : [ {
    "key" : "rpm.metadata.version",
    "value" : "19.300.0.9"
  } ]
},{
  "repo" : "yum-private-local",
  "path" : "some/path",
  "name" : "awesome_package-19.300.0.58-0.noarch.rpm",
  "properties" : [ {
    "key" : "rpm.metadata.version",
    "value" : "19.300.0.58"
  } ]
},{
  "repo" : "yum-private-local",
  "path" : "some/path",
  "name" : "awesome_package-19.300.0.59-0.noarch.rpm",
  "properties" : [ {
    "key" : "rpm.metadata.version",
    "value" : "19.300.0.59"
  } ]
} ],
"range" : {
  "start_pos" : 0,
  "end_pos" : 3,
  "total" : 3
}
}
```

This result includes version 19.300.0.9, which, [according to RPM spec](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Archive:Tools/RPM/VersionComparison), is older than what I am searching for (>= 19.300.0.58) and shouldn't be included in the results, but Artifactory finds it nonetheless, most likely due to its search comparisons being lexicographic.

Also note the ordering of the results, which **does** appear to use numerical sorting (version "19.300.0.9" comes before "19.300.0.58" and "19.300.0.59").

**Question:** is it possible to force Artifactory to use numerical ([SemVer](https://semver.org/)) comparison in search criteria? If not, is there any other way I can exclude irrelevant versions from the result list?

Comment: .include("@rpm.metadata.version")
   .sort( { "$asc": [ "name" ]}) -- You have sorted the result in asc order with name field. Is this the earliest version greater than equal to19.300.0.58 ?

Comment: @error404: yes, I have sorted on the name field b/c sorting on properties (e.g. @rpm.metadata.version) is not supported. As a matter of fact, `sort` clause is irrelevant here: my main problem is that I have expected to get only two matches in the result (.58 and .59), but I am also getting a (much earlier) .9.

Comment: I feel the result is proper the version of the awesome_package-19.300.0.9-1.noarch.rpm would be higher than the previous one as this one ends with -1 instead of -0. If it would have been -0 then the result should not be part of the aql

Comment: @error404: `-1` is in fact a property called `@rpm.metadata.release`, and is not related to `@rpm.metadata.version` property I use when searching. Artifactory correctly parses EVR (epoch/version/release) for deployed artifacts: if I search for artifacts using `items.find( 
   { "$and" : [ 
     { "@rpm.metadata.name": { "$eq": "awesome_package"}}, 
     { "@rpm.metadata.version": { "$eq": "19.300.0.9"}} ] 
   })`
I only get one result (as expected). It's just that `$gte` comparison treats version as a string, ignoring RPM spec that lays out (different) comparison semantics.

Comment: ok, I have not used the rpm so was not aware of the properties used. Can't you use created_by field to get the latest version ?

Comment: @error404: thanks for the idea, I haven't thought about it. I will probably have to resort to use sorting by `created` field: we never re-deploy artifacts, and almost never build older versions, so using the `created` (i.e. deployment timestamp) will work in most of the cases, which is good enough for me. Thanks again!

Comment: np! Happy that was able to help you. Written the same in the answer section. Also noticed that I said created_by it should be created(thanks for interpreting it right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not in lines with what is asked but instead of name sorting if done by the created field would also be helpful.

```
created:
```

Comment: thanks, upvoting your comment as an acceptable workaround.